# Renderer cannot be used in Service?

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to use Renderer in Service or just in component?

If I inject renderer into service I get error, that the Renderer provider is missing.

See plunker's console:

```
import {Injectable, Component, Renderer, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';

@Injectable()
class TestService {
  constructor(
    private _renderer: Renderer
    ) {}

  renderElement(elementRef: any) {
    this._renderer.createElement(elementRef.nativeElement, 'div');
  }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/e8qlznCVbvZnXbLTk36z?p=preview

Comment: What element do you expect to get injected for `elementRef`?  For a component or directive, this is the current element. A service doesn't have one. I don't use TS,  but I'm pretty sure the `ElementRef` constructor parameter needs a concrete type for the injector to know what to pass (`ElementRef` instead of `any`)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add ElementRef type, but it doesn't work with it either.

Comment: Didn't expect that. I just wanted to point that out as well. There is no element to inject for a service. What element do you expect to get injected? Where do you want to update the DOM?

Comment: You can use `RootRenderer` to get a `Renderer`, check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qjqB0CKUlMHZSkCLeRGz?p=preview). The idea comes from this [repo](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material/blob/9ecdff274be89c435cd453321e90b35d9e9f474e/ng2-material/components/dialog/dialog.ts#L56). All credits to @justindujardin.

Comment: thanks, that's is clever. it works fine. If you make an answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yea, like Eric said you can just pass it from the actual component to the Service and it will work.

HOWEVER, the responsability to render an object is of the component, not the Service, services are meant to handle business logic (retrieve the data mostly, depending on your app).

The whole idea is that you can reuse your whole services layer if you ever change your presentation framework/library or anything presentation related stuff at all, If you do things like that you'd be coupling your services to your presentation, making harder to make changes later on.

If you want to reuse the rendering logic between components, I'd create a parent abstract class with the logic and extend it with a Component, the children component would get injected the renderer and pass it to the parent class with the `super()` method that should call the parent's constructor.

At the very least you can make an @Injectable object like the proposed solution, but call it SomethingRenderer instead of Service and separate it from the rest of your real Data Services.

Comment: how is listening to global events on Window a Component's responsibility? You can add `window.addEventListener` but it seems it's not testable

Comment: I would point out there are many services inject an manipulate the dom. Toast, Dialog services. Services that deal with RTL, adding / removing classes for responsiveness or other reasons from and to the dom. I'm not sure this should be the accepted answer for this reason.

Comment: I think a service can have a role to create and inject DOM elements.

Answer (score 31):

Possibly duplicating with [Using Renderer in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070308/using-renderer-in-angular-4)

You cannot inject `Renderer2`, but we can run `RendererFactory2` to get `Renderer2` instance inside `@Injectable()` service.
There are two different ways of solving this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17824).

### Get an instance of Renderer2 inside Service

There is the way which Angular using internally in webworkers, for example.
I've solved the problem with the code below:

```js
import { Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
class Service {
    private renderer: Renderer2;

    constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
        this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    }
}
```

Parameters of `RendererFactory2.createRenderer` method are:

- `hostElement` with type `any`
- `type` with type `RendererType2|null`

You can see that `(null, null)` parameters are here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e3140ae888ac4037a5f119efaec7b1eaf8726286/packages/core/src/render/api.ts#L129

### Pass Renderer2 from component

```js
// declare public property in your service
@Injectable()
class Service {
  renderer: Renderer;
}

// pass renderer to service in your component file
class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(service: Service, renderer: Renderer2) {
      service.renderer = renderer;
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your first solution but it looks like is going against Angular rules. Have you used it in your projects and found any problems? Is it ok to use?

Comment: @PedroArantes It's not against the Angular way and I use it in production.
The only difference between solutions is that first creates new renderer, and the second uses existing instance.
Both are using public library methods. Also `RendererFactory2` is using internally in Angular for the same proposes.

Comment: another solution is to simply convert your `service` into a `directive`, adding the directive to your component's `HTML` template, and later accessing it like `@ViewChild(DirectiveClassName) directiveVariableName: DirectiveClassName;` from your component's `TS` file

Comment: how about testcases for this service file..??

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your reply! Do you happen to know if there is a performance disadvantage of using `renderFactory.createRenderer(null, null)` in a service in contrast to injecting it into a component and using it there? I am working with SVG and would prefer the tools-service to be responsible for creating a `SVGElement` - using `this.renderer.createElement(..., ...)`, but I am not sure if it is a wise decision or not so much. Do you happen to know?