# Using Renderer in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I understand why it's better to use renderer instead of directly manipulating the DOM in Angular2 projects. However, I have uninstalled, clear cache, reinstalled Node, Typescript and the Angular-CLI several times and I still get an error when trying to inject the Renderer.

```
import { Injectable, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}
```

> __zone_symbol__message: "No provider for Renderer2!"
>
> __zone_symbol__stack:"Error↵    at Error.ZoneAwareError

Does anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What class is the constructor a constructor from? Is it a component or directive? Is it a service?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Update:**

```typescript
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  private renderer: Renderer2;

  constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }
}
```

See more on this here: 
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17824#issuecomment-351961146

**Previous version:**

According to your imports

```typescript
import { Injectable, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core'
```

i suspect that you're trying to inject `Renderer2` in your service class. It won't work. You can't inject `Renderer2` in service. It should work for components and services that are provided within component.

We can take a look at source code https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.0.1/packages/core/src/view/provider.ts#L363-L373

```typescript
while (view) {
  if (elDef) {
    switch (tokenKey) {
      case RendererV1TokenKey: {
        const compView = findCompView(view, elDef, allowPrivateServices);
        return createRendererV1(compView);
      }
      case Renderer2TokenKey: {
        const compView = findCompView(view, elDef, allowPrivateServices);
        return compView.renderer;
      }
```

it checks only within element injector tree. And there are no other places when this token can be provided

So you have to pass `Renderer2` from component to service when you're calling some service method https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17824#issuecomment-311986129

or you can provide service within component

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class Service {
  constructor(private r: Renderer2) {}
}
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: `./app.component.html`,
  providers: [Service]
})
export class AppComponent { 
  constructor(private service: Service) {}
}
```

Comment: very interesting

Comment: Man, this answer saved my entire evening.

Answer (score 19):

You cannot inject `Renderer2`, but we can run `RendererFactory2` to get `Renderer2` instance inside `@Injectable()` service.
There is the way which Angular using internally in webworkers, for example.

I've solved the problem with the code below:

```js
import { Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
class Service {
    private renderer: Renderer2;

    constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
        this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    }
}
```

Parameters of `RendererFactory2.createRenderer` method are:

- `hostElement` with type `any`
- `type` with type `RendererType2|null`

You can see that `(null, null)` parameters are here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e3140ae888ac4037a5f119efaec7b1eaf8726286/packages/core/src/render/api.ts#L129

Comment: @Eugene.thanks for the answer.may i know why Renderer2 cannot be injected ? Since RendererFactory2 and Renderer2
 both are class so asked