# Service: No provider for Renderer2

Tags: angular, typescript

`Angular 4.2` with `Typescript 2.3`

I am refactoring a service that is responsible for creating a new script tag and adding it to the document.

Here is the old code:

```
loadScript(src:string){
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.src = src;
}
```

Now, I'd like to use the `Renderer2` to avoid doing direct DOM manipulation. So I've injected what I need in my service and updated the code:

```
constructor(private renderer:Renderer2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document){}

loadScript(src:string){
    const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body,script);
    script.src = src;
}
```

However, I run into this error:

> Error: no provider for Renderer2!

The service belongs to a `CoreModule` whose only import is `CommonModule` from `@angular/common`

[This plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MpsFO4E0EkKYuyKUh328?p=preview) demonstrates the problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070308/using-renderer-in-angular-4/43140852#43140852

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/iDIFRxzsm8bRpMTRdm8F?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the fast response. It was helpful info. I can't use the plunkr you linked to though because my service needs to be a global instance so that the same script won't be loaded by multiple components (service will not duplicate previous work).

Comment: You can init service with Renderer on root component

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17824#issuecomment-311982912

Comment: So the problem is that i'm trying to use a ModuleInjector to do an ElementInjector's job, right?

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Possibly duplicating with [Using Renderer in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070308/using-renderer-in-angular-4)

You cannot inject `Renderer2`, but we can run `RendererFactory2` to get `Renderer2` instance inside `@Injectable()` service.
There are two different ways of solving this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17824).

### Get an instance of Renderer2 inside Service

There is the way which Angular using internally in webworkers, for example.
I've solved the problem with the code below:

```js
import { Injectable, Renderer2, RendererFactory2 } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
class Service {
    private renderer: Renderer2;

    constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
        this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    }
}
```

In your particular case, it will be

```js
@Injectable()
class Service {
  private renderer: Renderer2;

  constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2, @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document){
    this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
  }

  loadScript(src:string){
    const script = this.renderer.createElement('script');
    this.renderer.appendChild(this.document.body,script);
    script.src = src;
  }
}
```

Parameters of `RendererFactory2.createRenderer` method are:

- `hostElement` with type `any`
- `type` with type `RendererType2|null`

You can see that `(null, null)` parameters are here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/e3140ae888ac4037a5f119efaec7b1eaf8726286/packages/core/src/render/api.ts#L129

### Pass Renderer2 from component

```js
// declare public property in your service
@Injectable()
class Service {
  renderer: Renderer;
}

// pass renderer to service in your component file
class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(service: Service, renderer: Renderer2) {
      service.renderer = renderer;
  }
}
```

Comment: for me all I needed in my service was document.documentElement.setAttribute('lang', 'The Lang');

Answer (score 17):

You can initialize service with an instance of `Renderer2` in root component

```
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  renderer : Renderer2;
}
...
class App {
  name:string;
  constructor(service: MyService, renderer: Renderer2) {
      service.renderer = renderer;
  }
}
```

See also

- [Using Renderer in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43070308/using-renderer-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 4):

I tried to implement this using render2, but in a service - leading to 'StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Renderer2]'-Error, as injecting Renderer2-Instance seems to not be possible. Solution was to inject RendererFactory2 and manullay create the reference within the service, like:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FgRendererService {
  /** Reference to render-instance */
  public renderer: Renderer2;
  /** CONSTRUCTOR */
  constructor(
    private _renderer: RendererFactory2
  ) {
    this.renderer = _renderer.createRenderer(null, null);
  }
  /** Add class to body-tag */
  addBodyClass( classToAdd: string ): void {
    this.renderer.addClass( document.body, classToAdd );
  }
  /** Remove class from body-tag */
  removeBodyClass( classToRemove: string ): void {
    this.renderer.removeClass( document.body, classToRemove );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

##### Important Note:

Whichever approach is appropriate for your needs it's important to realize that `Renderer2` can have many different implementations `DefaultDomRenderer2`, `BaseAnimationRenderer`, `DebugRenderer2`, `EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2` etc. For example, each component using ViewEncapsulation gets a different renderer.

If you inject Renderer2 in a service that is **provided by a sibling component** then you'll get that component's renderer automatically. This is important for ViewEncapsulation because it's the renderer that actually knows how to generate those `_ngcontent-appName-c339` attributes that scope your styles.

If you inject `Renderer2` at the root level, an ancestor component or from your `AppComponent` and then try to use it to generate HTML you'll get either no host attribute or worse the wrong one.

Be sure to test your expectations carefully if using SSR or web workers too.

None of this may matter for what you're doing but it's important to be aware of the reasons why there are different instances of `Renderer2`.