# 'No provider for Renderer' error in a service

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, angular2-services

I am trying to use Angular 2 `Renderer` class methods inside a service.

Firstly, I inject it into the class constructor like below:

```
    @Injectable
    export class MyService{
     constructor(private renderer: Renderer,
                 private _cd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

     myFunct(){
       this.renderer.setElementStyle(......);
      }
    ......
    }
```

With this the browser console is throwing an error stack:

```
   Error: No provider for Renderer!
at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://local.xyz.com:3000/vendor.bundle.js:30912:34)
at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://local.xyz.com:3000/vendor.bundle.js:28881:16)
```

I read several answers on StackOverflow related to this kind of question as well as a [thoughtram](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/09/17/resolve-service-dependencies-in-angular-2.html) blog post on Angular DI and tried using the `@Inject` in the service class constructor like below:

```
   constructor(@Inject(Renderer) renderer : Renderer){}
```

Still no success, still getting the same error. I am sure I am missing some trick here. It works when I use the same thing within a component, I don't know why it is not accepting it in service class.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710408/renderer-cannot-be-used-in-service

Answer (score 5):

You can always create a renderer via the `RendererFactory` as such:

```
@Injectable
export class MyService {
    private renderer: Renderer2;
    constructor(rendererFactory: RendererFactory2) {
        this.renderer = rendererFactory.createRenderer(null, null);
    }
}
```

By passing in `null, null` you are actually retrieving the default `Renderer` for the app so there shouldn't be much overhead

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround similar to that mentioned in the StackOverflow question in the comment above. In the component class, I instantiated the Renderer and bound it to a property in the service class, to use it. Though it worked but I am still not convinced using it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass it from the actual component to the Service and it will work.

But Service are not meant to put rendering logic while it should always be used to put the business logic.
So it should always be handled in Component itself as per good code practice.

Comment: I am using the service more of as a common class which can be used at multiple components to avoid redundant code. That is why I created a service which can be shared by all and also can help in maintaining state.