# Angular Universal and ElementRef/Renderer2.createElement

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-universal

I've ported an Angular 5 app over to Angular Universal using the steps outlined here: https://angular.io/guide/universal

I'm trying to port over some uses of document and window. It builds fine, but now I'm now getting this runtime error:

```
    ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError[LayoutDirective -> ElementRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[LayoutDirective -> ElementRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
```

And one of my Karma tests shows a similar error:

```
Chrome 63.0.3239 (Mac OS X 10.13.2) MyComponent should create FAILED
        Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MatIcon -> ElementRef]:
          StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatIcon -> ElementRef]:
            NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
            at _NullInjector.webpackJsonp.../../../core/esm5/core.js._NullInjector.get Users/project/node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:994:1)
```

I believe this is the code that broke things (old version commented out);

```
    @Injectable()
    export class MyService {
        @ViewChild('head') headEl: ElementRef;

...
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
                // const node = document.createElement('script');
                const node = this._renderer2.createElement('script');


                node.src = this.url;
                node.type = 'text/javascript';
                node.charset = 'utf-8';

                // document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
                this._renderer2.appendChild(this.headEl, node);

                node.onload = () => {
                    observer.next(true);
                    observer.complete();
                };
            });
```

Edit: Now I'm seeing this error:

```
Failed: _this._renderer2.createElement is not a function
        TypeError: _this._renderer2.createElement is not a function
```

Why would renderer2.createElement not be a function?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution. You can't actually use Renderer2 directly in a service, so I used the RendererFactory2 suggestion from here: [Renderer cannot be used in Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710408/renderer-cannot-be-used-in-service)

Then I changed this line:

```
this.renderer2.appendChild(this.headEl, node);
```

to this:

```
this.renderer2.appendChild(this._document.head, node);
```